# Loading arrays of different sizes into a single array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 100 arrays with the dimension of nx1. `n` varies from one array to the next (e.g, `n1 = 50`, `n2 = 52`, `n3 = 48` etc.). I would like to combine all these arrays into a single one with the dimension of `100 x m` with `m` being the max of `n`'s.

The issue I am running into is that as n varies, Matlab will throw out an error says that the dimensions mismatch. Is there a way to get around this so I can pad "missing" cell with N/A? For instance, if the first array contains 50 elements (i.e., `n1 = 50`) like this:

```
23    
31  
6  
...  
22
```

the second array contains 52 elements (i.e., `n2 = 52`) like this:

```
25    
85  
41  
...  
8  
12  
66
```

The result should be:

```
23 25  
31 85  
6 41   
... ...  
22 8  
N/A 12  
N/A 66
```

Thanks to the community in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider using [structure arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) for storing such datasets as it makes everything easier when merging them into a single array.

But to answer your question, if you have arrays like this:

```
a1 = 1:20; % array of size 1 x 20
n1 = numel(a1); % 20
a2 = 50:60; % array of size 1 x 11
n2 = numel(a2); % 11
... say you have nArrs arrays
```

Given `nArrs` arrays for example, you can create the desired matrix `res` like this:

```
m = max([n1, n2, .... ]);

res = ones(m,nArrs) * nan; % initialize the result matrix w/ nan

% Manually
res(1:n1,1) = a1.';
res(1:n2,2) = a2.';
% ... so on

% Or use eval instead like this
for i = 1:nArrs
  eval(['res(1:n' int2str(i) ', i) = a' int2str(i) '.'';'])
end
```

Now bear in mind that using `eval` is [NOT](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) recommended but hopefully that just gives you an idea as to what to do. If you did use structures, you can replace `eval` with something more efficient and robust like [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) for instance.

Comment: Preferable to `ones(m,nArrs) * nan` you could simply do `NaN(m,nArrs)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach without `eval`.

```
array_lengths = cellfun(@numel, arrays);
max_length = max(array_lengths);

result = nan(max_rows, num_arrays);

for r=1:num_arrays    
    result(1:array_lengths(r),r) = arrays{r}(1:array_lengths(r));
end
```

Some explanation:   I'm assuming your arrays are stored in a cell to begin with.  Here is some code to generate fictitious data with the dimensions you gave:

```
% some dummy data for your arrays.  
num_arrays = 100;
primerArrayCell = num2cell(ones(1,num_arrays)); % , 1, ones(1, num_arrays));
arrays = cellfun(@(c) rand(randi(50, 1),1), primerArrayCell, 'uniformoutput',false);
```

You can use `cellfun` with an anonymous function to get the lengths of each individual array:

```
% Assume your arrays are in a cell of arrays with the variable name arrays
array_lengths = cellfun(@numel, arrays);
max_length = max(array_lengths);
```

Allocate an array of `nan` values to store your result

```
% initialize your data to nan's.
result = nan(max_rows, num_arrays);
```

Then fill in the non-nan values based on the length of the arrays calculated previously.

```
for r=1:num_arrays    
    result(1:array_lengths(r),r) = arrays{r}(1:array_lengths(r));
end
```